# Book involving a child whose mother breaks into his piggy bank to bail out his brother, and he imagines waiting in his room until his body regenerates

Tags: identification-request

I think I read this in the early 1990s as a book checked out from the library in Ashland, KY. I didn't get very far into it, but an early scene made a huge impression on me. The protagonist wakes up to the sound of his mother smashing his [bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggy_bank) open to get to the money inside it. She explains that a family member (I think his brother) needed to be bailed out (I think actual bail). I want to say that the bank was a ceramic globe. The mother was apologetic about the situation and I think the protagonist was resigned to the fact that this family member was going to ruin his life in this way. They then reflected on something they'd learned in science class, that [the human body completely regenerates itself every seven years](https://www.livescience.com/33179-does-human-body-replace-cells-seven-years.html) (a common factoid) and imagines staying in his room, not moving, for those seven years, so that he can exit as a new person. I want to say he specifically references how pink his skin would be.

I know this is a weird fragment of a story, but I'm hoping that someone else remembers that opening scene as vividly as I do, and also remembers the title.